# Y coordinate isn't exact when getting a control's global screen coordinates

Tags: java, javafx, popup, coordinates, global

X is fine, but strangely Y is moved by a few pixels

```
Popup resultsList = new Popup();

Bounds textFieldBounds = textField.localToScene(textField.getBoundsInLocal());

ListView lsv = new ListView();
lsv.layoutXProperty().set(0);
lsv.layoutYProperty().set(0);
resultsList.getContent().add(lsv);

Window window = textField.getScene().getWindow();
double x = window.getX();
double y = window.getY();

resultsList.show(textField, 
                     x + textFieldBounds.getMinX(), y + textFieldBounds.getMaxY());
```

Has anyone had this problem so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the bounds of the text field relative to the *scene* and then adding the coordinates of the *window*. So you will be offset by any difference between the coordinates of the window and the coordinates of the scene (e.g. the size of the title bar).

Use

```
Bounds boundsInScreen = textField.localToScreen(textField.getBoundsInLocal());
resultsList.show(textField, boundsInScreen.getMinX(), boundsInScreen.getMaxY());
```

You could also do

```
// your existing code

double sceneX = textField.getScene().getX();
double sceneY = textField.getScene().getY();

resultsList.show(textField, x + textFieldBounds.getMinX() + sceneX,
    y + textFieldBounds.getMaxY() + sceneY);
```

but of course the first version is less verbose.